# What is the symbol used to represent “combination with repetition?”

Tags: combinatorics, notation

Does anyone know in which language is the capital H used to represent combination with repetition, like C being used to represent combination without repetition?

Comment: Your title and your question body seem to ask different questions: your title asks what symbol is used for this concept, while your question body asks what language uses a *given* particular symbol for it. Please make it clear what question you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the title question, $$\left(\binom{n}{k}\right)=\binom{n+k-1}{k}$$ is called $n$ *multichoose* $k$.